# Regarding the removal of /dev/diag Interface

Tags: android, interface, system.diagnostics, qualcomm, dm

everyone

I am currently reviewing the use of Diag Interface for SM-G988U Deveice(Android 11).

However, if i check the inside of the kernel, the existing /dev/diag has been removed.

We obtained an open source through the terminal manufacturer, and even if we checked the source, we could not confirm the Diag Interface.

Is the Diag Interface changed to something else? Or does the latest device not support Diag Interface?

I hope someone can help me out.

Thank you